# Fetching Core Data object in the background and tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I want to load Core Data objects in the background, and when it´s finished, should reload a TableView. The code below gives an empty tableView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Venue>!
 var venue:[Venue] = []
 var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      fetchRequest = Venue.fetchRequest()
      coreDataStack.storeContainer.performBackgroundTask {(context) in
           do {
                self.venue = try context.fetch(self.fetchRequesrt)
           } catch {
           }
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
           }
      }
}
```

But if we write code in viewDidLoad() without chunk above, all works fine and tableView is populated with data:

```
venue = try! coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequesrt)
tableView.reloadData()
```

What is wrong with the code above?
For advices I would be very grateful!

Edit. That's the right solution:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Venue>!
 var venue:[Venue] = []
 var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   fetchRequest = Venue.fetchRequest()
   coreDataStack.storeContainer.performBackgroundTask {(context) in
   do {
    let venue = try context.fetch(self.fetchRequesrt)
    venue.map {$0.objectID}.forEach{self.venue.append(self.coreDataStack.managedContext.object(with: $0) as! Venue)}
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
   } catch {
   ...
   }
  }
  }
}
```

One more solution to use NSAsynchronousFetchRequest class. The example above would look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var fetchRequesrt: NSFetchRequest<Venue>!
  var venue:[Venue] = []
  var asyncFetchRequest: NSAsynchronousFetchRequest<Venue>!
  var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!
  fetchRequest = Venue.fetchRequest()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest:fetchRequest, completionBlock: { [unowned self] 
   (result: NSAsynchronousFetchResult) in
  guard let venue = result.finalResult else { return }
   self.venue = venue
   self.tableView.reloadData()
   })
   do {
     try coreDataStack.managedContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
     } catch {
      ...
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `NSFetchedResultController` whenever interacting with Core Data and `TableView` itself. It is much stable and optimized than fetching data on your own.

I am very confused about your code, I have never seen a solution like that. Maybe you should make function with closure and on completion call reloadData, or put the whole block into `beginUpdates` like this:

```
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
coreDataStack.storeContainer.performBackgroundTask {(context) in
           do {
                self.venue = try context.fetch(self.fetchRequesrt)
           } catch {/*error goes here*/}
      }
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Anyway, I strongly recommend using `NSFetchedResultsController` because it is much easier for performing backgroundTasks.